# Why stored procedure stage in DataStage not working properly?

Tags: oracle, etl, data-warehouse, datastage, ibm-infosphere

I need to use the stored procedure stage.

Currently I'm making just for an example for how to use it right.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "STG"."TRUNC_TEST"
AS
BEGIN
    execute immediate 'truncate table TESTSP';
END;
```

That's my example of simple stored procedure.

My job design probably seen like this

```
Oracle Connector 1=>Transformer=>Oracle Connector 2=>Stored Procedure Stage
```

Oracle Connector 1 do Select, Oracle Connector 2 do Insert to TESTSP

My settings in the stored procedure stage

General : I've already put all the credential , with Transaction ISO as None

Syntax

```
Procedure Name :  TRUNC_TEST
Procedure Type : Transform (i've also tried to change it to Target)
Database Procedure Type : Stored Procedure
Generate procedure call (checked)
```

Parameters

```
Empty
```

Error Codes

```
Empty
```

NLS Map

```
Project Default UTF-8
```

Advanced

```
Execution mode :Default(Sequential)
Combinability : Default
Configuration file : default
```

In the Input tabs

General

```
Execute Procedure for each row (checked)
Transaction size : 0
```

Partitioning

```
Collector type Auto
```

Columns

```
Just brought all the columns from Oracle connector 2
```

Advanced

```
Default
```

The job showing green line and success, but the SP isn't working. It should've been truncate the TESTSP table, but when I do a `select *`, the data is still there.

Maybe my stored procedure is wrong since I'm still learning how to make it? Or maybe there is something wrong with my 'Settings' in the stored procedure stage?

Comment: You don't have a schema name in your truncate statement `truncate table TESTSP`. What schema do you think `TESTSP` is in? Why don't you take the uncertainty out and use a schema name in your truncate statement.

Comment: Thankyou Nick for replying! I've tried your suggestion to add the schema, and still didn't work.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "STG"."UPDATESP"
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE STG.TESTSP SET NUMBER = 99 where NUMBER=1;
END;

I've also tried with the UPDATE, well that is also no change eventhough i've already inserted 5 datas with values 1 to the field.

Is it maybe my ''settings" in the Stored Procedure Stage? Since I tried to execute my SP, it works fine. But in the Datastage it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Run the stpred Procedure on the command line - outsinde of DataStage - and check if it works. I think you are missing at least the () behind the procedire name....

Comment: Does this help? This is what came up first when I googled. https://etl-tools.info/en/datastage-faq-205_invoke-oracle-plsql-stored-procedure-from-server.htm

Comment: Dang YES! It did work Nick! You're a life saver!
Btw Thanks to you also Michael you've helped me so much before with my "dumb noobs" questions many times! 

I think the Stored Procedure can't be directly processed from Oracle Connector? So i changed my  Design to look like this

Oracle Connector 1=>transformer 1(has 2 branches)
transformer 1=>Oracle Connector 2
Transformer 1=>Transformer 2 => Stored Procedure Stage

Answer (score 0):

Every time you are running your job, you are just creating or replacing the SP definition.
You will have to call the SP in order to execute it.

That is the reason you are able to execute it outside.
I suggest you to create a generic SP in your database which will accept table name as parameter.

Once this is created, use SP stage to invoke the SP with column you want to truncate.
You can also use after SQL option in oracle connector to avoid extra SP stage.